# Unknown used space on hard drive

Tags: mac, hard-drive, space

There's an unknown space that is used on my hard drive. I've already use DaisyDisk and OmniDiskSweeper but both haven't detected anything.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "unknown space"? The 852.1 MB? Some disk space is allocated to the file system itself! On a virgin 64 GB HFS+ volume about 157 MB are occupied by it.

Comment: how can i delete it?

Comment: Please ask questions in your "question" but not in the comments...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any data on the drive, then format it. The data is probably a malfunctioning HFS+ journal.

If you do, it is either a HFS+ journal, or some cached data. It could also be the .Trashes folder. If it is, try clearing the trash with the drive plugged in, or just type `sudo rm -rf "/Volumes/DriveName/.Trashes"`.